# php Mail sending double content

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, sleep

I am working on a massmail script which sends an e-mail to every e-mail id present in a particular database.
But there is some issue.

Like I have following database:

```
id   email     link
1    a@bc.com  bc.com
2    b@cd.com  cd.com
```

And suppose the mail content is : 'Testing this script'

The scripts sends email to a@bc.com perfectly but second time it sends the email, i.e to b@cd.com the content gets doubled.

I mean the second recipient receives an e-mail like this :

> Testing this script
>
> Testing this script

The third recipient receives an e-mail with the content repeat three times and the fourth one receives it with four times and so on.

The script grabs e-mail addresses from the email field in the database and sends e-mail to them.

My Code:

```
<?
  include "header.php"; 
  include "config2.php"; 

$subject="Massmail";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass)
      or die ("Database CONNECT Error"); 
        $resultquery = mysql_db_query($database, "select * from $table");       
    while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($resultquery)) 
    { 
        $mailto=$query[$table_email];
        $domain=$query[$table_link];
$domain2 = str_replace(array('http://','HTTP://','Http://'), '',$domain);
$handle = fopen("http://$domain2","r") or die("Unable to open link ( $domain ). <a href='javascript:history.go(-1);'>Go back</a> and please try again  ");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
$contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
$contents = str_replace('window.location = "/abc.html"','window.location = ""',$contents);
$contents = mb_convert_encoding($contents, "HTML-ENTITIES", "auto");
}
$i = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.' . html;
$fh = fopen("/home/host/public_html/content/$i", "w");
fwrite($fh, $contents);
fclose($fh);
$filename = '/files/$i';
$message1 .= "Testing Mail Script Version 2";
        mail($mailto, $subject, $message1, $headers, "-f" . 'noreply@domain.com');
        echo 'Mail sent to '.$mailto.'<br>'; 
        sleep($seconds);
    }
  include "footer.php";    
  ?>
```

I have tried to echo the mail that has to be sent and I get this:

```
To: a@bc.com

Subject: Massmail

Message:
Testing mail script
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
to: b@cd.com

Subject: Massmail

Message:
Testing mail scriptTesting mail script
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It may be because, you are using in-correct looping script. show us your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code line: $message1 .= "Testing Mail Script Version 2"; the period is a concatenate, so each time you loop it, you duplicate the message another time.

Comment: I have just updated the code, I tried to echo the content using : echo "to: " . $mailto . "<br><br>Subject: " . $subject . "<br><br>Message:<br>" . $message1 . "<br>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br>"; .... Please have a look

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look back. I hope you were able to fix it already, but the fix would be to remove the period in $message .= 'Blah blah blah';  Edit: I see from your post below you did find it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. Sounds like your loop is not functioning correctly? If you can't post the full code, try to post an abstraction for us to diagnose your issue.

If you cant, I would look into looping based on the number of email address you have, not some arbitrary counter. That might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your table. With id, email, link, message structured as:

```
id     email         message 
1    a@test.com   hello, how are you doing..
2    b@test.com   hey, dude this is me..
3    c@test.com   we are sending you this...
```

Now, let's assume you have `100` records. What I would do is (assuming `$result` is a mysql array returning all the results from `mysql` ex `SELECT * FROM mail...`)

I would try:

```
for($i=0; $i <= count($result); $i++){

     $send = mail($result['to'], $result['subject'],
                  $result['message'], $result['headers']);

     if(!$send){
       echo 'e-mail, sending has stopped';
       break;
        }
    else{
        echo 'all e-mails are sent successfully'; }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this and update you if this fixes my problem. Thanks again =D
Though I have Updated the code, please have a look again if there's ny mistake.

Comment: No errors... I tested it with two entries............First entry got: Testing Mail Script Version 2

Second one got : Testing Mail Script Version 2
Testing Mail Script Version 2

Comment: I think, you have overly complicated your script. just try mine.

Comment: Alright I'l go for it. Will let you know if this works. Thanks so far :)

Comment: Well that did not made any changes except it sent the email few more times.  I am still receiving doubled content.

Comment: Well, then if that is the case, then it means, you have double entries in your database. check your rows for double content. or, when you do mysql check `SELECT * FROM mail WHERE message = message` and return rows, to see if you have double content

Comment: I have just two entries in the database so I can surely say there is no doubling there. also mysql query has been properly used. My full code is posted above, you can see. Thanks

Comment: You have used cumbersum codding, and many variable like `$table_email. $table_link, mailto, $message1` whose origin is unstated. I can't be of much help. But, I assure you give is some time, and try later. the problem does not seem that big

Comment: These values come from config2.php which I have included at the beginning. Well, Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29513/discussion-between-albab-and-php-noob)

Comment: I have just updated the code, I tried to echo the content using : echo "to: " . $mailto . "<br><br>Subject: " . $subject . "<br><br>Message:<br>" . $message1 . "<br>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br>"; .... Please have a look

Comment: Start from a normal script, just using the mail function with the 4 arguments, and then slowly build your way from there. because, I apart from telling you, your loop has a problem, I can not do much else.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I fixed it. @Pirion's post helped me. I changed

```
$message1 .= "Testing Mail Script Version 2";
```

to

```
$message = "Testing Mail Script Version 2";
```

And everything worked perfectly. Thank You So Much Guys For Helping Me Out.